# How to handle winter/summer time when formatting utc dates with Moment.js?

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I have built a small calendar app. Events are stored in my database with Dates in UTC. My js code fetches these events and formats the UTC date to the local date of the user machine. Now I live in Sweden so if the UTC time is 10:00, the frontend should show 12:00. This works fine for me except when it comes to summer/winter time. In the frontend the user can set an event to repeat at specific dates. So for example I could set an event that starts at the 20 of every month to start at 12:00. However, lets say I add events from august to December. Events in August-October will show 12:00. Events from November to December will show 11:00. However, if I set a single event to start for example in December, it will show the correct date. What is the best way to deal with this?

This is how I format the utc date to my local date:

```
var d = moment.parseZone(startDate).local().format('L LT')
```